# Running SSIS Project on two servers

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I'm running my SSIS project on two servers, one for development and the other for production. I've noticed that the project's execution time is 1 hour and 30 minutes on the development server, while it takes 2 hours and 30 minutes on the production server. Both servers have the same configuration. What could be causing this difference in execution time?
Thank you

Comment: The difference in time could be caused by one or more of the below facters.
* When you say the configuration is the same, do you mean Windows/SQL - or both?  
* Network latency differences in the servers.   Could be affected by when you run the jobs.
* Is the source data being utilised more when run on the Prod server?